# RedHat Openshift Wildfly 10 Server - rhc cannot access app after some time

Tags: ssh, openshift, redhat

I'm running a wildfly 10 app on RedHat Openshift.

It is running a very small web service with no database or anything special, and it works OK.

After a bit (an hour, 2 maybe) the app stops responding to 'rhc ssh appname' with the error:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:89:in
>   `next_packet': connection closed by remote host (Net::SSH::Disconnect)

The web service still responds, but I cannot ssh or tail the logs or anything to figure out what is wrong.

I have to force-stop it and start it again, and it starts working for awhile again.

How do I troubleshoot further?  I cannot see anything...

Answer (score 2):

SFTP into your app and look at the log files. I use WinSCP on windows.

Comment: That does not work.  I cannot ssh into it, and sftp do not work.  I can access the web server, but cannot ssh/sftp/get a terminal connection.

Comment: This happened to me once and it turned out to be a memory leak.  Maybe you could monitor your apps memory prior to it fully crashing.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, this is most likely your gear running out of memory.  I would suggest that you stop/start your gear, and then check for memory limit violations (https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues), you can also change the amount of memory that is allocated to the JVM (https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-jvm-memory.html).  The best solution would probably be to go ahead and use a larger gear size, probably at least a medium, but you'll have to see how things go.